# Bounding box coordinates for MKMapSnapshotter result

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm using `MKMapSnapshotter` to create a snapshot of an MKMapView. This is working great:

```
let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.367348, 115.653591)
options.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerCoordinate, 1000, 1000)
options.mapType = .Standard
options.size = CGSizeMake(2000, 2000)
let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
snapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler { snapshot, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
    else if let snapshot = snapshot {
        //process result
    }
}
```

What I'd like to know is the exact coordinates for the NE and SW corners of the resulting image. Is this possible? Is it a case of some simple maths based on the 1000m distance, or is the snapshot not that exact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it just requires some simple maths:

```
    func printTranslatedCoordinates(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, latitudeMetres: Double, longitudeMetres: Double) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, latitudeMetres, longitudeMetres)
    let span = region.span

    let northLatitude = coordinate.latitude + span.latitudeDelta
    let eastLongitude = coordinate.longitude + span.longitudeDelta
    let southLatitude = coordinate.latitude - span.latitudeDelta
    let westLongitude = coordinate.longitude - span.longitudeDelta
    print("\(westLongitude) \(southLatitude) \(eastLongitude) \(northLatitude)")
}
```